# Simple way of displaying images from parse.com database using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, parse-platform

I was working on a very simple page which just pulls and displays images from a table in parse.com. I do not have much experience with javascript which might be evident from the code below.

I need the images to show up in a chronological order. With the current code, it works fine most of the times but is a little buggy.

There are 2 main problems:

1) Sometimes, randomly, one particular new image might not come on the top and instead show up somewhere in between.

2) This page works on Firefox and Chrome but NOT on IE.

Is there a better way to implement this or is there something that I should change? Any help would be appreciated.

Page source-

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My parse images</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">




  <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    var config = {
    parseAppId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    parseRestKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    streamName: 'parse-demo'
};


var getPhotos = function() {
  var userImages = Parse.Object.extend("userImages");
  var query = new Parse.Query(userImages);

  query.find({
    success: function(results) {


      $('#photo-container').children().remove();


      for(var i=results.length - 1; i>=0; i--){

          var img = new Image();
          img.src = results[i].get("image").url;
          img.className = "photo";
          document.body.appendChild( img );


      } 



    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
};

  function refresh (timeoutPeriod){ 
    refresh = setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod); 
  }


$(document).ready(function() {

  getPhotos();

 // refresh(10000);

});

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer blocks mixed content. Since Parse's JavaScript SDK requires SSL, you need to host your app using HTTPS as well in order to access it from IE.

Comment: You can find the IE blog post about the subject here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx IE admitted this was "overly broad" and changed their stance in later versions. The blog also includes a sample workaround for mixed-mode hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you made one mistake. it was not working for me. Then i found that it is url() not url.
The amendment is img.src = results[i].get("image").url();

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>My parse images</title>
<meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.0.min.js">
 </script> 
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="main">




   <script type="text/javascript">
      Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

      var config = {
      parseAppId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      parseRestKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      streamName: 'parse-demo'
      };


      var getPhotos = function() {
      var userImages = Parse.Object.extend("userImages");
      var query = new Parse.Query(userImages);

      query.find({
      success: function(results) {


       $('#photo-container').children().remove();


       for(var i=results.length - 1; i>=0; i--){

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = results[i].get("image").url();
        img.className = "photo";
        document.body.appendChild( img );


      } 



     },
      error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
    };

   function refresh (timeoutPeriod){ 
         refresh = setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);
```

}

$(document).ready(function() {

getPhotos();

// refresh(10000);

});